# How to collect all files in a Folder and its Subfolders that match a string

Tags: c#, .net

In C# how can I search through a Folder and its Subfolders to find files that match a string value.  My string value could be "ABC123" and a matching file might be ABC123_200522.tif.  Can an Array collect these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, sMatch))
            {
                lstFilesFound.Add(f);
            }
            DirSearch(d);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```

where `sMatch` is the criteria of what to search for.

Comment: SLaks answer (below) is actually way better + more concise!

Answer (score 77):

You're looking for the [`Directory.GetFiles` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx):

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + search + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Answer (score 7):

**If the matching requirements are simple, try:**

```
string[] matchingFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles( path, "*ABC123*" );
```

**If they require something more complicated,** you can use regular expressions (and LINQ):

```
string[] allFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles( path, "*" );
RegEx rule = new RegEx( "ABC[0-9]{3}" );
string[] matchingFiles = allFiles.Where( fn => rule.Match( fn ).Success )
                                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful little extra there!

Answer (score 6):

```
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:/inetpub/wwwroot/demos");
 FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.aspx");
```

you can pass in a second parameter for options.  Also, you can use linq to filter the results even further.

check [here for MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

From memory so may need tweaking

```
class Test
{
  ArrayList matches = new ArrayList();
  void Start()
  {
    string dir = @"C:\";
    string pattern = "ABC";
    FindFiles(dir, pattern);
  }

  void FindFiles(string path, string pattern)
  {
    foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
      if( file.Contains(pattern) )
      {
        matches.Add(file);
      }
    }
    foreach(string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
      FindFiles(directory, pattern);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to SLaks answer, in order to use the `Directory.GetFiles` method, be sure to use the `System.IO` namespace.